# php call back script

Tags: php, callback

I am trying to make a callback function for my website. I have seen a few PHP scripts but I am having trouble linking the script to the input text boxes. My PHP script is called `callback.php`. This is my HTML code:

```
<form action="callback.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

        <label id="Name"><br><br><br><br>Name<br> 
            <input name="nameinput" type="text" style="width: 300px; height: 30px;" /> </label>

        <label id="Email"><br><br>Email Address<br> 
            <input name="emailinput" type="text" style="width: 300px; height: 30px;" />  </label>

        <label id="Number"><br><br>Phone Number<br> 
            <input name="numberinput" type="text" style="width: 300px; height: 30px;" />  </label>

        <label id="Subject"><br><br>Subject<br> 
            <input name="subjectinput" type="text" style="width: 300px; height: 30px;" /> </label>

        <label id="Question"><br><br>Question<br> 
            <input name="questioninput" type="text" style="width: 300px; height: 70px" />
            <br><br> </label>

        <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" />

        </form>
```

I have my form and I have tried using other PHP scripts and when I click the submit button on the form it acts as if it is a download. Does the script have to be on a `.php` page or can I incorporate it into the HTML and put it above the form?

Comment: Its should be in .php file if you are going to process the form action in the same file.

Comment: Looks like your server not support php, do you develop on localhost ?

Comment: If the PHP file downloads this usually means that your webserver cannot handle PHP files, create a PHP file called php.php and put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and see if that either downloads, or displays a long page.

Comment: does the whole webpage have to be .php?

Comment: Every single page in which you want to use PHP.

Comment: The form can be a HTML page, as you have `action="callback.php"` your browser will (once you hit submit) just send the information to callback.php.

Comment: callback.php would have to be a .php page to process the form, but the page the form is on does not, it can be plain .html

Comment: dan clarke i did php.php and when i clicked submit it just opened in a new page. thank you grant

Comment: could it be something to do with the .php script?

Answer (score 1):

If the page is being treated as a download, this means the server does not know how to serve the file. This may mean you don't have PHP installed or Apache may not be setup properly.

PHP can be in any file extension you want but Apache will need to know to process that extension with the PHP engine. For example (in `.htaccess`):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

This tells Apache to run the `.html` extension files with the PHP engine. The suggested way is to use `mod_rewrite` if you want the `.html` extension to show and keep PHP files with the `.php` extension.

HTML code can be mixed in with PHP code. I suggest reading up on the basics of PHP.